# Can't use fontawesomefx with kotlin and tornadofx

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

I'm trying create some JavaFX buttons with FontAwesomeFX icons using TornadoFX. This is the code

```
    data class ButtonInfo(val texto: String, val icon: GlyphIcon<*>)

    val list = listOf(
        ButtonInfo("Cadastro", FontAwesomeIconView(FontAwesomeIcon.ADDRESS_BOOK)),
        ButtonInfo("Corrida", MaterialDesignIconView(MaterialDesignIcon.RUN)),
        ButtonInfo("Classificacao", FontAwesomeIconView(FontAwesomeIcon.LIST)))

    list.forEach {
        it.icon.size = "3em"
        val bt = Button(it.texto, it.icon)
        bt.contentDisplay = ContentDisplay.TOP
        bt.minWidth = 200.0
        root += bt
    }
```

In compilation I get this error:

```
Type parameter bound for T in var <T : Enum<T!>!> GlyphIcon<T>.size: String! where T : GlyphIcons!
```

is not satisfied: inferred type CapturedTypeConstructor(*) is not a subtype of GlyphIcons!

The GlyphIcon is a Java abstract class with this declaration:

```
public abstract class GlyphIcon<T extends Enum<T> & GlyphIcons> extends Text
```

I don't know how turn around this error. If I declare:

```
data class ButtonInfo(val texto: String, val icon: Text)
```

I don't get the above mentioned error, but I miss '.size' property. How I can declare my class 'ButtonInfo' so that this code works?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You didn't post your complete class, but it looks like you try to run the `list.forEach` instruction outside any method or init block? Kotlin gets confused by the `size` accessor, use `setSize()` to avoid the issue.

Here is a complete class with minimal changes to your sample that compiles and runs, and shows you the icons in a vbox.

```
data class ButtonInfo(val texto: String, val icon: GlyphIcon<*>)

class IconView : View() {
    val list = listOf(
            ButtonInfo("Cadastro", FontAwesomeIconView(FontAwesomeIcon.ADDRESS_BOOK)),
            ButtonInfo("Corrida", MaterialDesignIconView(MaterialDesignIcon.RUN)),
            ButtonInfo("Classificacao", FontAwesomeIconView(FontAwesomeIcon.LIST)))

    override val root = vbox {
        list.forEach {
            it.icon.setSize("3em")
            button(it.texto, it.icon) {
                contentDisplay = ContentDisplay.TOP
                minWidth = 200.0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I used the `button` builder instead of manually adding to the root node.

Let me offer an alternative:

```
class IconView : View() {
    override val root = vbox {
        button("Cadastro").icon(FontAwesomeIcon.ADDRESS_BOOK)
        button("Corrida").icon(MaterialDesignIcon.RUN)
        button("Classificacao").icon(FontAwesomeIcon.LIST)
    }
}
```

Then you define this function in a utility file:

```
fun Button.icon(icon: GlyphIcons, minButtonWidth: Double = 200.0) {
    graphic = when (icon) {
        is FontAwesomeIcon -> FontAwesomeIconView(icon)
        is MaterialDesignIcon -> MaterialDesignIconView(icon)
        else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown font family ${icon.fontFamily}")
    }
    with(graphic as GlyphIcon<*>) {
        contentDisplay = ContentDisplay.TOP
        setSize("3em")
    }
    minWidth = minButtonWidth
}
```

It makes it much easier to see what's going on at the call site.

Also, the `setSize("3em")` is only there to support Scene Builder. Consider using the `glyphSize` accessor instead.

Comment: Wow. Nothing like be answered by the lead programmer! I'm in initial touch with kotlin and tornadofx. So, I don't know the best solutions for a problem. Anyway, thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Happy to help :) Keep the questions coming, it's good to get more info about TornadoFX here on SO!